# ajaxstart not working after sometime

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have this code in my jquery file which works fine but if the site kept idle for some time like 5 minutes,then it is not working.i couldn't able to find why this happens, please suggest me what are the things which affects ajaxStart and ajaxStop or how can i debug this.

> jquery

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function()
{
    loading =0;
    $(".ajaxLoaderModal").show();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the jQuery API: 
*If $.ajax() or $.ajaxSetup() is called with the global option set to false, the .ajaxStart() method will not fire.*

https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/

please check your configuration

Comment: Thanks dude that helped me a lot